# 'Feel like a jerk' VS 'feel like I'm being a jerk'

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

If I did something stupid, which of the following is correct/natural to express my feeling?

1. > I feel like a jerk.
2. > I feel like I'm being a jerk.
3. > I feel like being a jerk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your 'feeling' is.

"*I feel like a [jerk]*" doesn't necessarily mean that you consider yourself to be a jerk all the time. This sort of expression normally means that something has made you *feel* that way. Perhaps you've done or said something stupid, acknowledged your mistake, and now feel that people think this of you.

"*I'm being a jerk*" sounds like a reference to *behaviour*. 'Being a jerk' normally refers to someone acting foolish, perhaps out of character.

"*I feel like being a jerk*" is unusual - it sounds like you are considering behaving that way.

Note that, when describing someone else's behaviour, saying someone is *being* a jerk, or *behaving like one* would be quite different from saying the *are* a jerk (eg "He's a jerk"). That would be more of a judgement of their behaviour or personality in general rather than just a specific instance. But when speaking about oneself, it wouldn't be uncommon for someone to say something like "*I **am** a jerk*" upon realising that they have acted stupidly over a specific matter.

Also note that 'jerk' is almost exclusively US English. If British English speakers ever say it, it is with some irony or in imitation of American English. But, whatever word you choose, whether it be *idiot*, *jerk*, *fool* etc, the expressions are normally the same.